# jquery .each(function(index, element)) not working?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I wanted to get all the children tags inside a div:

```
<div class="form input">
            <label class="formLabel cFont cColor cMore" id="text" for="textInput">please input something</label>
            <input class="formInput" type="text" id="textInput">
            <label class="formLabel" id="check" for="checkboxInput">check here to toggle disable</label>
            <input class="formInput" type="checkbox" id="checkboxInput">
        </div>
        <button type="button" onclick="showClasses()">show classes</button>
```

I did the following:

```
function showClasses(){
        var children = $('.form').children();
        children.each(function(index, v){
            var classes = v.attr('class');
            console.log(classes);
        }); // end each
    } // end showClasses
```

and the console gave me an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLLabelElement> has no method 'attr'
```

Then, I change the code to :

```
function showClasses(){
        var children = $('.form').children();
        children.each(function(){
            var classes = $(this).attr('class');
            console.log(classes);
        }); // end each
    } // end showClasses
```

then it works.

So what is the different between .each(function(index, element)) and .each(function()) ? why can't i use the 1st one in my code?

Comment: just found out i missed the $() in the 1st piece of code ... ...

Comment: The error suggests that the `element` in the parameters of `each()` is a DOM node, not a jQuery object. Perhaps: `var classes = $(v).attr();`? Or, more commonly, `var classes = $(this).attr();`?

Comment: @David Thomas yes i missed the $() , thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `children.each(function(index, v){` - `v` is domElement. Try using `.attr` like below,

```
var classes = $(v).attr('class');
```

**Full code:**

```
function showClasses(){
    var children = $('.form').children();
    children.each(function(index, v){
        var classes = $(v).attr('class');
        console.log(classes);
    }); // end each
} // end showClasses
```